# MySQL pivot / query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  `Name and Post Code` ,
SUM( IF(  `Month` =  '2016-09',  `Qty` ,  '' ) ) AS Sep, 
SUM( IF(  `Month` =  '2016-10', `Qty` ,  '' ) ) AS Oct, 
SUM( IF(  `Month` =  '2016-11',  `Qty` ,  '' ) ) AS Nov, 
SUM( IF(  `Month` =  '2017-01',  `Qty` ,  '' ) ) AS Jan, 
SUM( IF(  `Month` =  '2017-02',  `Qty` ,  '' ) ) AS Feb
FROM  `Main` 
WHERE  `Corporate Group` =  'Brogans'
GROUP BY  `Name and Post Code` 
WITH ROLLUP;
```

I have executed the above code in MySQL to provide sales data by various customers in the database as shown below:

[image]

I have totals per month. (vertical/column totals). I would like to get totals per customer. (horizontal totals)

Table (`Main`) Structure:

```
ID - int(10)  
Corporate Group - varchar (25)  
Account Number - varchar (25)  
Name and Post Code - varchar (200)  
Post Code - varchar(50) 
Supplier Code - varchar (100)  
Description - varchar (200)  
Qty - varchar (50)  
Month - varchar (50)  
Code & Description - varchar (200)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Without knowing your table structure how one should know which columns  use the get what you need? Please, provide your table (or tables) structure and a sample of what would be your desired result. Also, do not post images, it is better to post table result as plain text so we can get the values and create our own setup to provide you a better answer.

Comment: The solution of SUM(`Qty`) gives me exactly what I was looking for.